# Calculating SD from percentiles

Tags: standard-deviation

How can I calculate SD from these values: mean, Min, Max, P25, P75?

Comment: Is there a specific assumption regarding the underlying distribution? At first thought, that would seem to play a role in my approach.

Comment: Perhaps use the z-score?  $z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$, where $z_{25} = -0.675$ and $z_{75} = 0.675$.  Of course, assuming X is distributed as Gaussian.

Comment: In general there will be a wide range of standard deviations consistent with those values; without additional assumptions there's just going to be bounds that the standard deviation would lay between. Do you also know the sample size? (Without it there'd still be asymptotic bounds). [If you have a particular set of values you're interested in it would simplify discussion.]